# Am I using Mongo's $and and $expr incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Here is my query:

```
   ctas.updateMany({
      $and: [
          {$expr: { $lt: ['$schedule.start', () => Date.now()] }},
          {$expr: { $gt: ['$schedule.end', () => Date.now()] }}
      ]
    },
   {
    $set: {isActive: true}
  }).then(res => {
    const { matchedCount, modifiedCount } = res;
    console.log(`Successfully matched ${matchedCount} and modified ${modifiedCount} items.`)
    
  }).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

I'm absolutely positive that start is less than Date.now() and end is greater than Date.now(), but I'm not getting any matches. Is my syntax wrong?

a snippet of my document in mongo:

```
schedule: {
    start: 1642564718042,
    end: 3285129434744
}
```

Edit: In case it makes a difference, I'm writing this code as a mongo scheduled trigger.

Update: If I replace the second expression with an obviously truth expression, { isActive: false }, it matches all the documents. Obviously Date.now()*2 (what I used to set schedule.end) is greater than Date.now(), so why is that second expression failing?

Comment: Missing `$`. Should be `$start` and `$end`. as you are accessing the document's field.

Comment: I tried that as well and it didn't work. I've updated the code to fix that though.

Comment: Hi, just saw you attached the sample data. So change to `$schedule.start` and `$schedule.end`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies. I just tried that and still getting 0 matches. :/

Comment: Why are you using `$expr`? It is not required in the query filter. $expr is useful in cases where you need to use the document fields on both side of the operators - and it is not the case here.

Comment: What would be the alternative? I'm new to mongo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Missing `$`. And make sure your [field paths](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#field-paths) are correct. `$schedule.start` and `$schedule.end`.

And another concern is that both `schedule.start` and `schedule.end` are with Timespan value. So you need to cast them to date via `$toDate`.

```
db.collection.update({
  $and: [
    {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          {
            $toDate: "$schedule.start"
          },
          new Date()
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      $expr: {
        $gt: [
          {
            $toDate: "$schedule.end"
          },
          new Date()
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  $set: {
    isActive: true
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RA1l7p_zF5B)

Comment: I figured it out. I changed () => Date.now() to just Date.now() and it works. Thank you so much for your help.